# About Operating System, about page-table entries status bits

Tags: operating-system

In the movie *The Social Network*, when Mark Zuckberg was in class, the teacher asked this question:

> Suppose we're given a computer, with a 16-bit virtual address, and a page size of 256-bytes,the system uses one-level page tables that start at address hex 400, may be you want DMA (Direct Memory Access) on your 16-bit system. Who knows? The first pages are reserved for hardware flags, etc. Assume page-table entries have eight status bits. The eight status bits would then be ...

Mark Zuckberg answered:

> One valid bit, one modified bit, one reference bit and five permission bits.

How did he get this?

Answer (score 3):

Intel nomenclature in parentheses.  The 'valid' (present), 'modified' (dirty) and 'reference' (accessed) bits are the minimum set of bits you need for a demand paging manager and MMU.
The 'valid' (present) bit is used by the MMU to know whether the page is mapped to a valid physical address.

The 'modified' (dirty) bit is used by the demand paging manager to determine if the page being evicted needs to be written to backing media.  As accessing backing media can be considered an expensive operation, you really want to keep this to a minimum--especially when writing to it as that is generally slower than reading from it.

The 'reference' (accessed) bit is useful to the demand paging manager to figure out how to age the pages it controls.  You don't want to evict the most frequently used pages as that would require saving and/or loading them repeatedly from backing store (which has already been stated as SLOW).

The remaining five bits are gravy.  They are free to use as permission and/or option bits.  For example, can the page be accessed by supervisor and/or user threads?  Is the page available for write, or is it read-only?  What is the caching strategy to be used on the page?

Hope this helps.

Sparky

Answer (score 2):

http://chomaloma.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/social-network-inaccuracies-regarding.html

That does explain it a little

Comment: Excellent explanation, spoiler: "_..there is no way to infer this knowledge from the question being asked. Unless the students had read the mind of the professor, or had notes printed out.._"

Answer (score 1):

How did he get the answer?---That is just movie BS.

If you take the number of bits in the address and subtract the number of bits used to represent a page, you get the number of bits available for the processor to use as system status bits.

With that information, he could identify the number of system status bits

The usage of those bits is another story. The allocation of system status bits is system dependent. Maybe they exist, but I don't know of any 16-bit virtual addressing system. So he's not referring to any specific type of system.

A reference bit is not used by all systems (e.g. VMS). That's not even mandatory.

Hollywood magic.