# How to find the largest page size that could be used for a specific virtual to physical address mapping?

Tags: linux, operating-system

How do you answer the following question:

"If we have a system where virtual address 0x52D2C3A3 mapped to physical address 0x13A103A3, what is the largest page size that could be used for this mapping?".

Don't skip on the details, I'm trying to understand. I also don't just need the answer, I already have it. I just want to know how you solve a question like that.

Comment: The one sentence cut out of the context in your homework question does not make any sense and does not include a hint how to find the correct answer. It is very nicely aligned with http://stackoverflow.com/a/26800888/2626313

Comment: Tell me about it... There is no context surrounding the sentence. This IS the question, nothing else. No hint, no nothing. 

The answer is: "The largest page size would be 16K because the 14 low order bits are are the same, and 2^14 = 16,384 = 16K. The low order bits make up the page offset which is always the same between a virtual address and its mapping to a physical address." But I don't understand how you come up with that.

Comment: Assuming this is not a hypothetical addressing on an abstract CPU and assuming that the OS is Linux then after reading http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/witchel/372/lectures/15.VirtualMemory.pdf the question may make sense if you take for granted that virtual address is `(page number, offset)` and physical address is `(frame number, offset)` and all the address translation does is mapping `page number` into a `frame number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low order bits make up the page offset which is always the same between a virtual address and it's mapping to a physical address. Therefore, we need to find the low order bits of the hex values given.

0x52D2C3A3 = 0000 0000 0101 0010 1101 0010 1100 0011 1010 0011

0x13A103A3 = 0000 0000 0001 0011 1010 0001 0000 0011 1010 0011

Since the first 14 bits are the same, the largest page size would be 2exp14 = 16 384 = 16k.